# Time to digital converter (TDC) for time of flight (TOF) applications. 66.6 picosecond sample

Tags: rf, adc, clock-speed, vhf

[image: Question TDC for TOF]

My question is in regards to dynamic range of short time period TDCs, or alternative solutions to a time to digital application.

If further information is required, please ask.

[TDC datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tdc7200.pdf)

Question.

TDC7200 datasheet says,
Measurement Range:
– Mode 1: 12 ns to 500 ns
– Mode 2: 250 ns to 8 ms

I wish to measure 66.6ps as my fastest sample and 3.33ns as my slowest sample.

Both mode 1 and 2 are outside of my desired range, however I see the datasheet also says 55ps resolution. Further down it also says LSB = 55ps.

Does this mean that if I wait for 12ns then all samples thereafter are within 55ps accuracy?

In other words:

- fastest sample = 12ns
- next sample = 12.055ns
- next 12.11ns
- next +55ps
- etc etc until the nBit register is full?

Comment: I think there are some kinds of interferometers for such applications.

Comment: I was about to suggest something with a ring oscillator, until I read the TDC2700 note, which integrates it all! So, is your question 'can I do better than the TDC2700?' ? Because the datatsheet spells out the dynamic range.

Comment: Thank you Gregory, I will study interferometers further.

Neil_UK: I think I got myself confused. would you please confirm something for me? I have edited my post with the new question at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding

> Does this mean that if I wait for 12ns then all samples thereafter are within 55ps accuracy. In other words. fastest sample = 12ns , next sample = 12.055ns

Actually the [TDC7200 datashet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tdc7200.pdf) specifies:

```
+-----------------+------------------------------+-----+-----+-----+------+  
|      Param      |         Description          | min | typ | max | unit |  
+-----------------+------------------------------+-----+-----+-----+------+  
| T1STARTSTOP_Min | t_min between Start and Stop |  12 |     |     | ns   |  
| T1STOPSTOP_Min  | t_min between 2 Stop Signals |  67 |     |     | ns   |  
+-----------------+------------------------------+-----+-----+-----+------+
```

table adapted from datasheet, formatted thanks to [online tool](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/)

So if first sample is at 12ns then next sample cannot arrive before 12+67=79 ns.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried with [ACAM](http://www.acam.de/products/time-to-digital-converters/tdc-gpx/) chips? they are not in 66ps range. But they are pretty good and provide good support and kits.

Alternative way  is to use ultrawideband communication. Please refer to [decawave](http://www.decawave.com/)

Comment: Thank you Sanu!
TDC-GP22 by ACAM looks great, I will research ACAM further! I think I understand how my application will work now. I just wish to confirm that LSB and resolution works in the manner that I have suggested at the very bottom of my question? thank you soo much for your suggestions!

Comment: Please refer the datasheet. I didn't tried in that way. Also try to find a very stable tx/rx circuit for TOF. Happy to here that the answer is useful :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this app note at TI: [Interleaved Short Time Measurements using TDC7200](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/snaa288).  It explains a way to make measurements in the 0 to 12ns range as long as the measurement can be repeated.  Assumption is that the measurement will not change significantly between repetitions.

Answer (score 1):

The crucial part here is:

- what is the width of a pulse?
- how many pulses are there in short succession?

The precision is not a problem. For example our company cronologic build the xTDC4 time to digital converter:
https://www.cronologic.de/products/tdcs/xtdc4-pcie

It measures the arrival time of pulses at a precision of 13ps, which fulfills your precision requirement.
However, pulses must be at least 200 picoseconds wide and consecutive pulses on the same input must be at least 5 nanoseconds apart. Many other TDCs are slower than that.

Using deserializers you can measure pulses as small as 30ps at rates of up to 15GHz with a precision of 30ps. We also habe a solution for that.
However this can only measure a certain amount of pulses at once because the data rate is to high for continuous readout.